# how to write simple group sql query to linq query in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

we simply perform any group by query on db table like

```
select sum(rs) from data where id=3;
```

How do i write similar query on datatable using LINQ?

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
var sum = data.Where(x=>x.id==3).Sum(x=>x.rs)
```

**Update:**

You need something called Linq to Datatable
Example here:

```
var dt = new Datatable();
//fill dt here
//row -> every row in datatable
//row.Field<T>(columnName) -> access to the specific row cell from the column of name 'columnName' and of type T

var sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row=>row.Field<string>("Id")=="3").Sum(row=>row.Field<int>("rs"));
```

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb399401(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: suppose my datatable name is dt and same query i want to perform on datatable then how i can do it??

Comment: @HirenRaiyani do you have DbContext, or model created?

Comment: I have datatable, i want to fire query on datatable.

Comment: @HirenRaiyani, I updated my code for DataTable. Is it clear for you now?

Comment: @Mrozu but my ID is string and RS is int then how can i do?

Comment: @HirenRaiyani, I added some comments to my code and provided link to documentation

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var result = data.Where(a => a.id == 3).Sum(a => a.rs);
```

Comment: But i am perform this query to datatable then??